# Is this an undocumented override of the Split method?

Tags: c#

I just found that not only does this code compile, it seems to split the string on any whitespace.

```
List<string> TableNames = Tables.Split().ToList();
```

However it didn't show in the intellisense and it's not on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Is this just an undocumented override? And is it dangerous to use because of that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not an override. In this case, the compiler translates `Split()` into `Split(char[])` with an empty parameter.

Split [is defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as

```
public string[] Split(
    params char[] separator
)
```

`params` lets you specify a variable number of arguments, including no arguments at all. When no arguments are provided (as is in your example), the `separator` array will be empty.

From the MSDN page linked above:

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters.

This is why you're seeing the string split on whitespace. This is just default behaviour rather than an undocumented feature, so you're free to use it without fear of unusual side-effects. Well, unless default behaviour changes in a future version of .NET, but that seems fairly unlikely to me since whitespace is a reasonable default.

Comment: Beat me by fifteen seconds. Curses! (+1) :)

Comment: +1 Yep, and the `ToList()` is an extension method from `System.Linq`.

Comment: Brilliant and prompt! This is why I love StackOverflow.

Comment: Just to be nitpicky, the argument is not null. It is an empty array, not a null reference -- you've made both claims and only one of them is right. :-)

Answer (score 3):

From the [remarks to String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

> If the separator parameter is Nothing
>   or contains no characters, white-space
>   characters are assumed to be the
>   delimiters. White-space characters are
>   defined by the Unicode standard and
>   return true if they are passed to the
>   Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

I's call that documented behavior, personally. :)